# Action in Form1 after Form2 is closed

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-7, file-manager

I try to make file manager in Delphi and there is I need to be able create new folders.

So, i got my **Main Form** and when I press button `Create New Folder` other form appears where I can type new folder name and confrim or cancel creation.

So I created new form for folder creation and make it invisible.

I made it like this - here I got procedure in **Main Form**

```
procedure TfolderFrame.CreateFolder;
begin
  newFolderDialog.Visible:=true;
end;
```

And here's new **folder form**

```
unit FolderDialog;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,fileOperations, StdCtrls;

type
  TnewFolderDialog = class(TForm)
    edtName: TEdit;
    lblName: TLabel;
    btnOK: TButton;
    btnCancel: TButton;
    procedure btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    FolderName:String;
    kindOfAction:char;
    hasUpdated:Boolean;
  end;

var
  newFolderDialog: TnewFolderDialog;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TnewFolderDialog.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FolderName:=edtName.Text;
  if CreateDir(FolderName)
  then begin
    ShowMessage('New folder created!');

  end
  else begin
    ShowMessage('Creation failed. Error : '+ IntToStr(GetLastError));
  end;
  newFolderDialog.edtName.Clear;
  newFolderDialog.Close;
  hasUpdated:=True;
end;

procedure TnewFolderDialog.btnCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  newFolderDialog.edtName.Clear;
  newFolderDialog.Close;
end;

procedure TnewFolderDialog.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hasUpdated:=false;
end;

end.
```

The problem is - when `TfolderFrame.CreateFolder;` called it just make **new folder form** visible and then procedure ends. But I need to made some other thigs after folder will be created, something like `Refresh` or stuff.

I've been trying to do it like this:

```
 procedure TfolderFrame.CreateFolder;
    begin
      newFolderDialog.Visible:=true;
     while not (newFolderDialog.hasUpdated) do begin
       if(newFolderDialog.hasUpdated) then
       RefreshAllStuff;
     end;
    end;
```

But programm just stuck because of it.

How could I call `Refresh` procedure in **Form1** only after confirming of folder creation in **Form2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redesign your code to use `TForm.ShowModal()` instead, eg:

```
procedure TfolderFrame.CreateFolder;
begin
  if newFolderDialog.ShowModal = mrOk then
    RefreshAllStuff;
end;
```

```
procedure TnewFolderDialog.btnOKClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FolderName := edtName.Text;
  if CreateDir(FolderName) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('New folder created!');
    ModalResult := mrOk;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Creation failed. Error : '+ IntToStr(GetLastError));
end;

procedure TnewFolderDialog.btnCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModalResult =: mrCancel;
end;

procedure TnewFolderDialog.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtName.Clear;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But why with such thing as `ShowModal()` it works like that? I mean if there were other condition procedure just were  like check `if`and then ends, isn't it?  And one more thing delphi 7 not detected `FormShow` method but however, I used `Activate`

Comment: `ShowModal()` makes the caller wait for the modal Form to close. Setting the `ModalResult` causes a modal Form to close. `FormShow` is the event handler for the Form's `OnShow` event. You should use that event instead of the `OnActivate` event. When a Form is shown, `OnShow` is triggered only once, but `OnActivate` can be triggered multiple times, whenever the Form loses and then regains input focus.

Comment: Oh, interesting! Thanks again! Btw, I use OnShow() method so I use it now.